# Why am I getting the error: cond: expected a clause with a question and an answer

Tags: if-statement, scheme, lisp, racket

Why am I getting the error: `cond: expected a clause with a question and an answer, but found a clause with only one part`? What am I doing wrong?

Basically, I have to find out if the discriminant is a positive / negative number.

```
(define (has-real-roots? a b c)
  (cond
    [(positive? (- (square b) (* 4 a c)))]
    [else false]))
```

Comment: I'm guessing you ar enot using `#lang racket` but some other language. Could you include what language you are using? Why do you use `cond`? What extra does it provide compared to just having `(positive? (- (square b) (* 4 a c)))` as the body?

Answer (score 4):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/advanced.html#%28form._%28%28lib._lang%2Fhtdp-advanced..rkt%29._cond%29%29), each clause in a `cond` expression requires two parts: the "question" (a condition), and an "answer" (the value to return). Your code is missing the "answer" part for the first clause, in this case returning `true` would be appropriate:

```
(define (has-real-roots? a b c)
  (cond [(positive? (- (square b) (* 4 a c))) true]
        [else false]))
```

But you don't really need to use a `cond` here, this is simpler and does the same thing:

```
(define (has-real-roots? a b c)
  (positive? (- (* b b) (* 4 a c))))
```

Comment: 3rd example is `[test-expr]` the result will be the truthy value. I don't think OP uses `#lang racket`

Comment: I updated the link to point to the Student Language's documentation, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

[Racket Documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/)

It just you have many one arm if than else what to check or we call it `case` so we use `cond`. You should match language syntax.

```
#lang racket
(cond
    [#false 'you-wont-entry-this-part-because-test-express-is-false]
    [#false 'you-wont-entry-this-part-because-test-express-is-false]
    [#true 'entry-this]
    [else 'last-condiction])

#|
(cond
  [test-express-1 if-test-express-1-is-true-do-this]
  [test-express-2 if-test-express-2-is-true-do-this]
  ...
  [else if-test-express-1-to-n-all-false-do-this])
|#
```